# How to install a Maven/Gradle project along with all its dependencies to a local repository?

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a Gradle project that depends on several open-source projects up on Maven Central. I'd like to install the project – along with all its direct and transitive dependencies – to my local maven repository, so that I could later zip it all up and put it on offline machines.

How do I do it with Gradle/Maven?

Comment: Have you tried "mvn clean install" command?

Comment: Doesn't that install only the project's artifacts w/o dependencies to the local repo?

Comment: It will put everything including dependencies n local repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mvn dependency:get` [plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) will fetch the artifact with all dependencies to the local repository.

I had also developed a [plugin](https://github.com/chaschev/maven-installation-plugin) to install remote artifacts to a local machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to later ZIP up your project w/ dependencies and move them to a different machine, you could try [Maven's appassembler plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/). It collects all dependencies and creates a launcher, all in the target folder, ready for deployment.

But note, this, by default, creates a flat directory structure with all dependencies, it doesn't preserve the Maven format. It also has the option to create a repository.